# Как получить папку письма IMAP?

Tags: php, email, imap

Собственно интересуют входящие сообщения, которые не попали ни в одну папку и лежат в корневой INBOX. Смотрел заголовки и тело письма, там нет ни одного упоминания о том в какой папке находится письмо.

Вижу пока только такой вариант:

- По отдельности получаем письма за N период из всех папок и записываем
  их в массив
- Читаем все входящие письма за N период и записываем их в массив
- Удаляем элементы из массива со всеми входящими? которые попали в
  первый массив

Но кажется мне что решение такое не шипко правильное и есть более адекватные способы. Кто сталкивался направьте плз.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы будете получать письма так (стандартный способ):

```
$server = '{imap.yandex.ru:993/ssl}';


$mbox = imap_open($server, "Login", 'pass')
     or die("не удалось подключиться: " . imap_last_error());

$MC = imap_check($mbox);


$result = imap_fetch_overview($mbox,"1:{$MC->Nmsgs}",0);
foreach ($result as $overview) {
    echo "#{$overview->msgno} ({$overview->date}) - From: {$overview->from}
    {$overview->subject}\n";
}
imap_close($mbox);
```

ТО вы **ВСЕГДА** будете получать письма из папки INBOX. То есть письма без папки.

**А если вам надо получить письма конкретно из папки:**

```
$server = '{imap.yandex.ru:993/ssl}';

$connection = imap_open($server, "login", 'pass');

$mailboxes = imap_list($connection, $server, '*');

print_r( $mailboxes );
```

Вы должны получить что-то типо такого:

```
Array
(
    [0] => {imap.yandex.ru:993/ssl}Входящие
    [1] => {imap.yandex.ru:993/ssl}PHP
    [2] => {imap.yandex.ru:993/ssl}Servers
)
```

Название могут быть на кирилице, нужно будет декодировать.
Теперь например нам нужно взять письма из папки PHP, то делаем переподключение:

```
imap_reopen($connection, $server.'PHP');
```

И уже делаем запрос для получения писем.

---

Всё это я проверял на яндексе, mail, google. Везде нормально.

Comment: Вы не поняли мой вопрос, я понимаю как получить письма из конкретной папки. Но вот в чем дело, у меня во входящих создано несколько папок. Я хочу получить все входящие письма, которые не попали в созданные папки.

Comment: @Dizzy221  "ТО вы ВСЕГДА будете получать письма из папки INBOX. То есть письма без папки." - цитата из ответа. Я сейчас пробовал, у меня всегда при стандартном запросе письма без папок, то есть те что лежат в папке "входящие".

Comment: ну это не так. видимо из за того что папки созданы во "входящих", от туда я получаю письма и в папках тоже

Comment: @Dizzy221 А попробуйте сделать `imap_reopen` конкретно на папку "Входящие".

Comment: Пошаманил с imap_reopen, но без результатов, может я не верно использовал. К чему реопен должен привести?

Comment: @Dizzy221 переподключается на конкретную папку, и дальнейшие действия будут происходить с указаной папкой. Странно, сейчас на яндексе перепроверил, всё как должно работает.

Comment: $mbox = imap_open("{imap.yandex.ru:993/ssl}", $mail_login, $mail_password);

imap_reopen($mbox, "{imap.yandex.ru:993/ssl}INBOX");

$count = imap_num_msg($mbox);

все равно выдает все сообщения, включая папки